# How to Prevent Multiple instances of wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, desktop-application

How to prevent multiple instances of WPF application? is there any proper way? also, need help to Prevent the same login multiple instances on different Machine.

Comment: Possible Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-wpf-application?

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, check the Mutex class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.8).